# BigDecimal scale and calculations

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I use `BigDecimal` to do calculations.
For the result of a calculation I do:

```
result.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

When using `.divide` method of `BigDecimal` a scale and rounding is required, so now I do it like this:

```
BigDecimal result = bigDecimal1.divide(bigDecimal2, 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

So I just use a big enough scale to be sure calculations will be right.
But I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing calculations with BigDecimal and I have doubts about this...

So any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: @jarnbjo If I'm doing it right? And if not, then how should I? ...

Comment: And you provided us with which functional requirements to allow us to decide if you're doing it right or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a clear idea of what you consider to be the right answer.  If the error is less that 1e-10, is that ok or does it need to be 1e-20 or 1e-30 etc.  For many division result, you cannot get an exact result because the result is represented as a decimal.

BTW: if you need less than 15 significant digits, this is the accuracy of using a `double` and you might not need to use BigDecimal.

e.g.  is 1/3 considered to be 0.333333333 or 0.333333333333333333 but its never going to be exactly right (i.e. infinite in length)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right.

You can find on [JavaPractices some examples with BigDecimal](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13).